# how to change the content of a float variable based on a string input

Tags: java

```
   i want to change the value of a float variable based on a string
```

I AM NEW TO JAVA SO BE KIND :P

```
 this is what i tried so far but it's not working
```

the program should ask the user to input a letter for an alphanumeric grading system , if the input contains a - sign the program should decrement the value of the grade by 0.3.
 if the input contains a + sign the program should  increment the grade by 0.3 .
else the program should pring the value of the grade

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.String;

public class AlphaNum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float A=4,B=3,C=2,D=1,F=0;
        System.out.println("Enter a letter grade : ");
        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Alpha = value.next();
        float num=Float.valueOf(Alpha);
        if (Alpha.endsWith("-"))        
        {
            num =(float) (num-0.3)
            System.out.println("Numeric value : " +num )

        }
        else if (Alpha.endsWith("+"))
        {
            num=(float) (num+0.3);
            System.out.println("Numeric value : " +num );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Numeric value : " +num );
        }

    }

}
```

i want the value of A which is 4 to be changed to 4-0.3 if the input string is A-
   tried Float.parseFloat method but it didn't work

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions and don't start variable names with capital letters. Name your variables `ace`, `acevalue`, and `value`-

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. `if (Ace.endswith("-")) {AceValue=AceValue-1}`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, you mean `aceValue`?

Comment: @jhamon If you like. My point is that a name like `Acevalue` is reserved for a type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value.nextFloat()` to just pull out the number from the input and then `value.next()` to pull out the sign.

Comment: Yes, I meant using the scanner to parse the float rather than having the scanner pull out a String and then using Float.valueOf, which requires a numeric string. So `float num = value.nextFloat();`